# Swift on Ubuntu - No such file or directory

Tags: swift, bash, ubuntu

Trying to install swift on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 server. Followed the guide on Swift.org.

- download the install package
- fetched the gpg keys
- verified the .sig file
- extracted the file and added the usr/bin subdir to my PATH

However when I try running swift I get "No such file or directory"

Swift seems to be found:

```
icanzilb@underplot:~/public$ which swift
/home/icanzilb/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-25-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin/swift
```

Path is correct:

```
icanzilb@underplot:~/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-25-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin$ echo $PATH
/home/icanzilb/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-25-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin:...
```

But can't run it:

```
icanzilb@underplot:~/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-25-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin$ swift
-bash: /home/icanzilb/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-01-25-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin/swift: No such file or directory
```

=====

Update 1: I tried the development and stable builds of Swift from swift.org and the .sig checks out but still getting the same error.

Both the `swift` executable and my Ubuntu are 64 bit.

Comment: Maybe some libraries are missing? `ldd \`which swift\`` could give relevant info in this case.

Comment: it says "not a dynamic executable" ... I got a 64bit ubuntu so that's not the problem, I wonder what it is?

Comment: On my install [all libs linked to the Swift executable (screenshot)](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFnSCZ-753dB9aEjcEAdcSISn9O3O-9iJfs) seem to be 64 so it shouldn't be the problem - but clearly your installed libs are the issue, given your ldd error message, otherwise you would get something similar to my screenshot.

Comment: Try `./swift` (mind the leading point and slash).

Comment: @uselpa `./swift` also produces the same error message ... it looks like the problem is about the file not being a "dynamic executable" but I have no idea how to fix that

Comment: This happens because the executable's dynamic loader (ld.so) can't be found. Often this is due to running 32bit binaries on 64bit systems without 32bit libraries installed (`apt-get install libc6:i386`), other times because it's compiled for a different distro.

Comment: @thatotherguy My first thought, earlier, was about the 32bits problem but OP states that their install is 64bits, so I concluded it was a problem with one of the linked libraries, needed by this executable, not being installed. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: @EricD. OP states that their OS is 64bit, but doesn't say which architecture of Swift they downloaded. This error only occurs when the loader is missing. If any other library is missing you get a more straight forward "error while loading shared libraries".

Comment: @thatotherguy Ah, right. Different error message indeed. So my answer's solution was not good. Deleted.

Comment: `libc6:i386` was up to date, re-installed it just in case but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like this is a problem of an architecture mismatch, as indicated by one of the commenters, or a corrupted download.  The swift executable is in the path and is picked up by `which`.  Judging from the name of the directory where it is located, it is indeed for Ubuntu 14.04.  I would try the following:

```
file `which swift`
```

This should tell you it is an ELF 64-bit executable, dynamically linked, etc.  If that is not the case, you have a corrupted binary somehow.

Then do

```
uname -a
```

which should identify your system as Ubuntu 14, x86_64 among other things.  If that is the case, you probably have a corrupted binary.  Unpack the downloaded package again and retry.  If your system is not x86_64, then you are on a wrong architecture.

Update 2/4/2016:

Based on the additional info you provided about the binary and the architecture, I tend to believe this is a platform mismatch.  The output of `uname` doesn't show it is an Ubuntu box.  Besides, the Linux kernel is 4.4.0, and the binary is for 2.6.24.  I can successfully run the same binary on an Ubuntu 14.04 installation with a 3.19.0 kernel.  The kernel version difference is not necessarily a problem in itself, but an indicator that the platform may not be a standard Ubuntu 14.04 install.

As another check, could you please do `cat /etc/os-release` and `cat /etc/lsb-release`?  Those files should indicate if the platform is indeed Ubuntu.  If it is, then I'm wondering how you ended up with this late kernel version.  It is possible some other components of the OS are also too recent and incompatible with the Swift binary.  This may be some strange custom Linode image...  If you have a machine you can use, virtual or physical, try downloading and installing a standard Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I also thought at first it could be a 32/64 bits mismatch but here's what I get: the swift file is `ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24` and my ubuntu is `Linux underplot 4.4.0-x86_64-linode63 #2 SMP Tue Jan 19 12:43:53 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` ... re-downloaded the tar.gz few times but nothing changed :[

Comment: just to add - the .sig of the download file checks out. getting both the sig and the tar from here https://swift.org/download/#latest-development-snapshots (the build from Jan 25th)

Comment: I didn't notice you added more info there :) Here's the output: icanzilb@underplot:~/public$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

Comment: Well, according to /etc/os-release it is an Ubuntu box.  However, the output of `uname -a` does look strange, especially the kernel version.  Have you tried a different Ubuntu installation?